# Google App Engine "Check For Updates" not working

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-apps

For some reason my GoogleAppEngineLauncher isn't checking for updates correctly. If I click Help > Check For Updates, I get this:

[image: Help > Check For Updates]

My GAEL is version 1.9.26, but the newest one is 1.9.28. When I go to deploy my app on the command line, it says I need to do an update, but then checking for updates doesn't work. I know I can just go to their website and download it, but I want to make sure there isn't a possibly deeper issue here.

[image: Command line when deploying an app]

[image: GoogleAppEngineLauncher > About]

Answer (score 0):

You might be hitting a glitch specific to your version of 1.9.26's GAEL. Just follow the procedure that the warning recommends: visit https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads with your browser, and download and install the latest GAE SDK for PHP for your machine.